# jsfiddle - how do I retrieve a previously saved fiddle

Tags: save, jsfiddle, reloading

I need to do some html/css/js and stumbled across jsfiddle.
It looks like an excellent sandbox for developing/trying code.
I have registered an account & profile
I created a simple fiddle, named it, and then closed my browser.
New when I reopen jsfiddle my panels are blank I cannot find my original fiddle to reload.
How do I reload previously saved code?

thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Click on `your profile -> dashbord` : http://jsfiddle.net/user/dashboard/
then select your saved code.

Comment: So simple.  I'm surprised I couldn't find a post on this.

Comment: @user2978241 Why don't you accept this answer then?

Comment: Simple, but not intuitive for me.  +1

Comment: I know that I have much more saved fiddles. But when click on "Your fiddles" I dont see all of them?

Answer (score 2):

Now you have to push button [image] then it appears a menu > Your fiddles

Comment: Yeah, press the "power button", cause that's intuitive. I have visited this post twice now, because I forgot that the "power button" is the account button.

Answer (score 1):

well it's **2021** things have changed ;-)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's 2023 and things have changed again. Click on your User-name dropdown and you'll find **My Fiddles** there.
[image: My Fiddles in DotNetFiddle]